# ios7 can't run on device :invalid hex digit 59 error?

Tags: xcode, ios7

I am trying to run on the device my app, after having the ios7 beta version .
I see the default screen on the iPhone , than i get this error  :

```
Reply contains invalid hex digit 59The program being debugged is not being run.
```

than some text about GDB free license , and this :

```
gdb stack trace around reply contains invalid hex digit:
```

I couldnt find anything about this error .

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to product> edit scheme , 
change there to LLDB . that solved it for me .